# get the data-attribute using closest returning null

Tags: jquery

I have some set of `div` which are having `class(es)` based on its functionalities, from that, I just tried to get the `data attribute` of the `first div` from the `last div`. So that, I decided that `closest` will suits my requirement. but unfortunately it is returning `null`. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my snippet.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="DivApplication">
  <div class="DivImg DivImgRun DivImgLeft" data-internalid=16></div>
  <div class="DivAppName">Application Title</div>
  <div class="DivTime">Created: 23-06-2013 | Edited: 23 July 2013 </div>
  <div class="DivImg DivImgReport DivImgRight">report</div>
  <div class="DivImg DivImgDelete DivImgRight">delete</div>
  <div class="DivImg DivImgEdit DivImgRight">edit</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".DivImgEdit").click(function(){
        alert($(this).closest('.DivImgRun').data('internalid'));
    });

});
```

**RESULT:**   `NULL`

---

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpazu/1/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `.siblings` instead of `.closest`

```
$(".DivImgEdit").click(function(){
     alert($(this).siblings('.DivImgRun').data('internalid'));
});
```

closest look's among  parents, in  your case, the desired element is sibling and not the parent

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/Rpazu/2/

Comment: Minor nitpick: `closest()` looks for parents *and the element itself* if it matches the selector.